# Java- How to turn off class sharing

Tags: java

Hello all Im using Visual VM and to use the profiler section I get a messages stating:

To profile an application running on JDK 6, you need to turn off class sharing for the application otherwise the application may crash. To turn off class sharing, start the application with -Xshare:off argument.

How do I do this?

Comment: Um..."start the application with -Xshare:off argument".

Comment: How are you launching the application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse, go to Run->Run Configurations, find your run configuration, and add the `-Xshare:off` in the arguments.

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA 12 go to Run -> Edit Configurations and do the same.

Comment: in "vm" arguments or "program" arguments?

Comment: -X should be vm arguments. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Answer (score 3):

as it states in message you need to start the application with the command line argument

```
-Xshare:off
```

exactly how to do this will depend on the environment you are running your app in, but from the command line you can run

```
java -Xshare:off myclassfile
```

as the other answers point out you can configure this in your ide if you are using one

Comment: I think you want `-Xshare:off` before the class file otherwise it is sent as an argument to the class.

Comment: You just passed -Xshare:off to myclassfile as parameter.